# Symfony 2 collection type, validation doesn't work and "adder" method called with NULL value?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

My `Product` **entity** has an "adder" method (explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)) to add entities of type `ProductVariant`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductVariant", mappedBy="product", 
 *     cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
protected $variants;

/**
 * @param ProductVariant $variant
 * @return $this
 */
public function addVariant(ProductVariant $variant)
{
    if (!$this->variants->contains($variant)) {
        $this->variants->add($variant->setProduct($this));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

`ProductType` **form** type is adding a collection of `ProductVariantType`:

```
$builder->add('variants', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new ProductVariantType(),
    'allow_add'    => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false, // ensure addVariant and removeVariant calls
));
```

**Problem #1 (validation)**: when I add a new variant (using add button/JavaScript) the new embedded form isn't validated. If I left blank all fields (i.e some of them are required) validation passes. *Validation occurs only filling some fields*.

**Problem #2 (`addVariant` call)**: `addVariant` is called with `NULL`, probably because the problem #1.

Some `ProductVariant` fields:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $code;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Range(min=0, max=2147483647)
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $quantity;
```

I'm using the following JavaScript to add/remove variants:

```
<script>
    $(function () {  
        $('.btn-add').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var holder = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target')),
                proto  = holder.attr('data-prototype')
                            .replace(/__name__/g, holder.children().length - 1);

           holder.append(proto);
        });

    });
</script>
```

And of course, the prototype:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="variants" 
    data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.variants.vars.prototype)|e }}">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <a href="#" class="btn-add" data-target="variants">Add variant</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% for variant in form.variants %}
        {{ form_widget(variant) }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Finally the (simple) controller code:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('product', $product)
        ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->flush();

        return $this->redirect(
            $this->generateUrl(
                'me_test_product_edit',
                array('id' => $product->getId())
            )
        );
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Comment: I am stuck at the same issue, how did you end up resolving it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure nested validation one need's to add the  [`Valid`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) constraint to your property holding the collection. (which you already did)

Further please note:

> By default the error_bubbling option is enabled for the collection
>   Field Type, which passes the errors to the parent form. If you want to
>   attach the errors to the locations where they actually occur you have
>   to set error_bubbling to false

([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html))

Please don't forget to clear your cache (symfony's and your opcode cache additionally) after introducing new annotations.

Comment: Thanks for helping. It's there (above `$variants`) as annotation. Changing the error bubbling doesn't help too..

Comment: Do the parent form's fields get validated correctly and show the form-errors?

Comment: could you add your controller code and the form-types to the question please? Do you have `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` in your `ProductVariant` class? otherwise there might be no validation-mapping for `ProductVariant`.

Comment: I've added my controller code. And yes - I'm using the `Assert` annotation. If I fill (say) `quantity` with an invalid value I get error messages for both `code` (*this field is required*) and `quantity` (*this value is invalid*). If i leave them both blank no validation occurs! This problem is driving me crazy...

Comment: can you please try to replace `NotBlank` with `Length` + `min=1` ?

Comment: I replaced with `Assert\Length(min="5")`. Typing just 1 character gives me the obvious error, the variant isn't persisted as the main form is INVALID. Leaving the field `code` blank gives me no errors (valid form) and `addVariant` is called with `NULL`. Am I'm missing something?